# How display the most recent item in LazyColumn? - Jetpack Compose

Tags: list, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, lazycolumn

- I have a product list and a shopping cart.
- I add the products to the cart.
- As the first item in the list of products added to the cart I want to view the last product I added.
  How can I view the list of products added according to this order?

Comment: Just order the items in the viewmodel

Comment: You need to add the logic to sort the products as required in the Viewmodel

Comment: Sort items object list according to some values of the item such as maybe time of adding, itemid generated while adding etc. and do the logic in viewmodel, expose it to the lazycolumn. cheers